# Button in CardLayout not working

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

So I'm using cardLayout in one of my programs and I'm trying to make it so that when you click a button the next panel loads. I have a panelHolder class where the cardlayout is held and every time the button on the panel is pressed, it would call a method in the panelHolder class that depending on the button sets a certain boolean variable to true and calls repaint (where the panels are shown). For some reason my button isn't working and I can't seem to find out why. Can someone help me?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SheetReader101 extends JFrame {
    public SheetReader101(){
        super("SheetReader101");
        setSize(2000,1000);
        setLocation(0,0);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        PanelHolder pg2 = new PanelHolder();
        setContentPane(pg2);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        SheetReader101 z1 = new SheetReader101();
    }
}
class PanelHolder extends JPanel { // HERE
    CardLayout clayout = new CardLayout();
    PianoGameContent x;
    tutorial y;
    boolean [] paneldecide;
    PanelHolder() {
        super();
        y = new tutorial();
        x = new PianoGameContent();
        setLayout(clayout);
        this.add("Tutorial", y);
        this.add("FreePlay Mode", x);
        paneldecide = new boolean[15];
    }
        public static void main(String[]args){
            PanelHolder z1 = new PanelHolder();
            z1.run();
        }
          public void run(){
            layoutShower(0);
         }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        public void layoutShower (int decide){
            {
                PianoGameContent y2 = new PianoGameContent();
                PanelHolder.this.add("Piano", y2);
                System.out.println("intro slide run");
                if(decide == 1){
                    PanelHolder.this.add("Piano", y2);
                    System.out.println("testing11");
                    clayout.show(PanelHolder.this,"Piano");
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use paintComponent in this way, this isn't how painting should be done, or how CardLayout works. Instead, add all your components to the panel and simply call CardLayout#show when you need to

Comment: does button react on the actionperformed method? or was an action not declared for the button

Comment: In your tutorial class, you're creating a new instance of PanelHolder, which has no relationship to the instance which is on the screen. Generally, I prefer to have a navigation controller which I can pass to my child views, which can tell it when they want to change, it's then up to the controller to decide how to make the change

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's what I had initially and it didn't works so I tried using it in paintcomponent. I edited the post and put the version I had before this.

Comment: @DarkV1 The button does react, I put a s,o.pln line in the same if statement as the one where the panel is supposed to show up and it runs. It's just the panel not hsowing up is my problem.

Comment: Panel not showing is a revalidate() validate problem

Comment: @Ken Shikinami Im not going to post that as a solution because I am unsure.

Comment: @DarkV1 `CardLayout` should take care of it, it's part of what it does

Comment: Ok, I wasnt sure if it updated itself.

Comment: Again, don't wait to add you components to the `PanelHolder`, add them all up front and then, when you need to, call `CardLayout#show`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I "suspect" that the core problem has to do with the original code you posted, where you're making a new instance of `PanelHolder` in your child view's `ActionListener` and then are attempting to switch views, this new instance has no relationship to the instance that is on the screen.

There are a few ways you can manage `CardLayout`, my preferred way is to use some kind of "navigation" controller which defines how navigation works, for example, you could have "next" and "previous" or "back", or you could define the actual views that can be displayed, ie `showMenuView`, `showTutorialView` etc, depending on how much control you want to give your sub views.

The following is a simple example which demonstrates the basic idea, it uses a `enum` to define the available views (as it has more meaning than `0`, `1`... and I don't need to remember the actual names of the views, the IDE can provide auto correct for that ;))

I create and add each view up front when I create the `PanelHolder`, I also pass each view an instance of the `NavigationController`, so they can interact with it

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication1013 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication1013();
    }

    public JavaApplication1013() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new PanelHolder());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public enum View {
        MENU,
        TUTORIAL,
        FREEPLAY;
    }

    public interface NavigationController {
        public void showView(View view);
    }

    public class PanelHolder extends JPanel implements NavigationController {

        private CardLayout cardLayout;

        public PanelHolder() {
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            setLayout(cardLayout);

            add(new MenuView(this), View.MENU.name());
            add(new TutorialView(this), View.TUTORIAL.name());
            add(new FreePlayView(this), View.FREEPLAY.name());
        }

        @Override
        public void showView(View view) {
            cardLayout.show(this, view.name());
        }

    }

    public abstract class ViewPane extends JPanel {
        private NavigationController controller;

        public ViewPane(NavigationController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }

        public NavigationController getController() {
            return controller;
        }

        protected void showView(View view) {
            controller.showView(view);
        }

    }

    public class MenuView extends ViewPane {

        public MenuView(NavigationController controller) {
            super(controller);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            JButton tut = new JButton("Tutorial");
            JButton freePlay = new JButton("Free Play");

            add(tut, gbc);
            add(freePlay, gbc);

            tut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    showView(View.TUTORIAL);
                }
            });
            freePlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    showView(View.FREEPLAY);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class TutorialView extends ViewPane {

        public TutorialView(NavigationController controller) {
            super(controller);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JButton menu = new JButton("Menu");

            add(new JLabel("Tutorial"), gbc);
            add(menu, gbc);

            menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    showView(View.MENU);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class FreePlayView extends ViewPane {

        public FreePlayView(NavigationController controller) {
            super(controller);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JButton menu = new JButton("Menu");

            add(new JLabel("Free Play"), gbc);
            add(menu, gbc);

            menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    showView(View.MENU);
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Take a closer look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details